# WordPress login form code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I have the following in a WordPress sidebar widget that serves as an online community for my niche. Right now I am able to display the form when the user is not logged in and to display the "Welcome to the Community!" message when the user is logged out -- which is great. However, the login functionality doesn't seem to be working. Could I please get some help?

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://domain.org/wp-login.php"        
 method="post">
    <p class="login-username">
        <label for="user_login">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" 
                        size="20" />
        </p>
    <p class="login-password">
        <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" 
                        value="" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p class="login-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-
                        primary" value="Log In" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" 
                       value="https://domain.org/" />
        </p>

    </form>
<?php } else { ?>
               <h4>Welcome to the Community!<h4>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_login_form();
} else {
    echo '<h4>Welcome to the Community!</h4>';
}
```

You can also pass a configuration array to `wp_login_form()` See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

Comment: Thanks @Rob - I didn't realize there was a function to display the login form! Instead I coded my own simple form :-) All the Best.

Comment: Edit: @Rob, can you help me -- the form isn't logging in. https://tinyurl.com/crcrohx -- (on right sidebar)

Comment: It's posting to the wrong url `https://haiticonnects-patricknommensen.netdna-ssl.com/wp-login.php`. Check your settings.

Comment: That's odd. It's using my content delivery network by default instead of wordpress site url?